# Testing multicollinearity in cox proportional hazards using R

Tags: r, cox-regression

I would like to assess multicollinearity in a cox proportional hazards model by calculating  Variance Inflation Factor (VIF). The vif-functions in packages like {car} does not accept coxph objects.

Is there a way to calculate VIF for cox models in R?

Comment: Isn't the VIF designed for least square regressions ? If I'm right, you shouldn't use it in a Cox regression, which is performed by maximising likelihood.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I found this quotation, which indicates VIF can be used for cox models.

"You can use the vif command after running a regression. "Because the concern
is with the relationship among the independent variables, the functional
form of the model for the dependent variable is irrelevant to the estimation
of collinearity." (Menard 2002, p. 76).

Menard, 2002. Applied logistic regression analysis, 2nd Ed."

Found at: http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-09/msg00334.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite correct in your comment above that the VIF depends only in the X values. The `vif`-function in 'package:car' will accept any model that responds to `vcov`, `coef`, and `model.matrix` which should happen with `coxph` in 'package:survival', so assuming you have a fit-object, this should give you results:

```
library(survival)
library(rms)  # one possible source for a `vif`-function .... there are many
cvif <- vif(  testfit1  ) #assumes testfit from :  lrm, ols, psm, cph, Rq, Glm, glm
```

(Not yet tested since you offered no working example.)

This is a test case construction after copying the example in another question and modifying to construct a 'coxph'-object:

```
treatment <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), levels = c(1, 2), labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)), levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))
numberofdrugs <- rpois(84, 5)+1
healthvalue <- rpois(84,5)
y <- data.frame(healthvalue,numberofdrugs, treatment, improved)

testfit1 <- coxph(Surv(healthvalue, rep(1,nrow(y) ) ) ~numberofdrugs+treatment+improved, data= y)
```

Comment: I did not get the example above to run. It works when removing the vcov function: ie instead "cvif <- vif(testfit1)", but I am not sure if the results then are valid?

Comment: Agree. Suspect a change in the rms package. Edited to update to current behavior.

Comment: There are also `vif` functions in the "HH" and "car" packages. However, the `VIF::vif` does NOT calculate variance inflation factors